# Determining if a jQuery JSON object is an array, dictionary or value?

Tags: jquery, json

In my JSON (retrieved via `$.getJSON`), I have a data element that can contain either a single value, a dictionary or an array. What function can I call to get its type?

Comment: What about `typeof` keyword?

Comment: Can you give us more context of the possibilities returned?

Comment: `$.type()` is very helpful.. will tell array from object even http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

Comment: define 'dictionary'. in, javascript, an array and a dictionary are pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @undefined: `typeof []==typeof {}`

Comment: @kennypu: Well, an array is an array in JSON and a dictionary is a dictionary in JSON

Comment: @charlietfl: That does what I need